# Why does boot fail with my custom kernel at the mknod step?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, linux-kernel

I want to build a custom kernel under Ubuntu. I configured and built the new kernel. The new kernel hasn't initrd and comes from vanilla source. I build this new monolithic kernel only with drivers it needs.

When I try to boot the new kernel I'm stuck at the `mknod` step. It tries to `mknod` new devices like `/dev/sda1` `/dev/vca4`. It fails because the root partition is mounted read-only.

I think the problem is that I've lost something about my hardware. If I boot with the default Ubuntu kernel, I haven't got any problems. Could anyone help me to understand why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

On boot, the root filesystem is almost always mounted read-only, so that you can run `fsck` on it. Once you're done, it's customary to remount the root filesystem read-write using something like:

```
mount / -o remount,rw
```

Although, since you're using Ubuntu, compiling a kernel should be far simpler than this. If you're not already using it, I recommend using `kernel-package` to compile the kernel. Simply get the package and kernel sources, unpack, and say something like

```
make-kpkg -j3 --initrd binary
```

This will then build `.deb` packages which you can install the usual way (`dpkg -i SOME-FILE.deb`)

Answer (score 1):

You should have a `devtmpfs` or `tmpfs` mounted at `/dev` and managed by `udev`; thus the directory is writable regardless of the state of `/`.  On Ubuntu, this is usually set up by the initramfs; did you build and load one with your kernel?

Comment: hi, well I have tmpfs built, but neither devtmpfs nor initramfs. The first does not exist in kernel menu and the second I don't want to build into the kernel

Comment: @user17545 Ubuntu's `/sbin/init` assumes that the initramfs's `/init` has already set up the root filesystem with `/dev`, `/dev/pts`, `/proc`, `/run`, `/sys`, etc. all already mounted as the appropriate psuedo-filesystems.  If you are going to use Ubuntu's init system without their initramfs, you will either need to create an initramfs that performs the same actions or change init.  Well, `CONFIG_DEVTMPFS_MOUNT=y` will automount `/dev` if you're not using initramfs, but the rest is still up to you.

Comment: yes, ok, I built my new kernel with     `CONFIG_DEVTMPFS_MOUNT=y`  but nothing was changed. If u need of my .config let me know.